# Where is residential power voltage reduced to home level from the street line level?

Tags: electrical

- What is the potential/voltage of the power line on a city street?
- Where does the potential/voltage of the line drop to the indoor value, e.g., 120 V in the US?
- If I need to upgrade the whole electric circuitry of a house, do I need to worry about the high voltage and if so, where does the high voltage starts to drop down to the indoor value coming into the house?
- To address the concern expressed in the comment below, I am looking to hire an electrician to upgrade the electric circuitry including the panel, meter, distributor, weather head and riser. I am wondering what are actually involved and what kind of price I would expect to be charged. The house is a single family house in Sacramento county, CA, USA.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement

Comment: @Ack: It is about home improvement as I have now stated the reason.

Comment: The answer is to call an electrician. If you need to upgrade the whole electric circuitry of the house and you don't know about the transformers from utility power to residential power, please don't burn your house down.

Comment: This is also very broad with 3 questions. The first 2 could be considered related enough for one question (though off-topic), while the 3rd is related (because it's talking about electricity), but shutting off power to the house is unrelated to transmission line voltages.

Comment: Frankly, the slant of the question and follow on comments smells a lot like "I'm planning to do something with the utility conductors and have no grasp of how dead that will make me" but ...whatever... Not to mention how dead (or homeless due to the fire) you can get messing with 240, particularly before it hits your main breaker, when you think it's 110 and that makes it "safe." If you do survive that, the utility will have a fun time suing you into homelessness anyway.

Comment: I agree with @Ecnerwal - your knowledge of residential wiring seems _extremely_ thin, and that lack of knowledge can _kill_ you! If you're planning on doing this work yourself, _please_ spend a _LOT_ of time learning (a licensed electrician in the US will spend about _5 years_ of book learning & OTJ apprenticeship) **before** you start, or plan on hiring this out. We'd love to answer your questions, but you have to be alive to ask them

Comment: What is missing here is clarification of **intent**: Is this: *I am going to get some serious electrical work done (professionally, properly, in coordination with utility, permits, etc.) and am just curious as to how/where voltage gets converted to my usual 120*, which is 100% a good reasonable safe question, **or** is this *Hmm, I want to try and bypass the meter (but can't tell you that) or I want to see if more voltage would be "better" (but I can't tell you that), so I'm wondering when/where/how something other than 120V gets to/is near my house* **which would be a bit of a problem**.

Comment: @Hans _Why_ do this? Do you just have nothing better to do with your time? Seems like an absolute waste of time, effort, and money.

Comment: @Ack: I added the reason for the question.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: I just edited my question to address your concern.

Comment: @Hans -- perhaps it'd be better to ask "what's involved in an electrical service upgrade?" directly instead of coming at your real question "through the back door" so to speak...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Well, the voltage question itself is an offshoot of the main question. Then people start to ask me why I asked the voltage question. This is the answer which is now accused of being distracting. It is hard to please everyone. I actually do not understand how and why the original voltage question itself is off topic.

Comment: @Hans -- basically, you were asking about something that's a function of the utility's system -- for anything you do with a house, you can treat the utility as a "black box" that supplies the nominal mains service voltage.  anything higher than that is contained entirely within utility gear :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The power delivery utility company distributes the AC power to locations away from the power generating stations using high voltages. This is done to help minimize the amount of power loss in the distribution wires and cables. The power loss is always related to the amount of current being distributed to the loads. For each doubling of the voltage used in the distribution network the amount of current for the same load is cut in half.

The voltage levels used will depend in part upon the type, location and distance that section of the power grid needs to deliver electrical power to the consumer loads. Voltages can be in the 1000s of volts.

When high voltage power distribution reaches a residential neighborhood or a business center transformers are used to step the high voltage down to the voltages used in the homes and businesses. Pictures of some typical power transformers are shown below. Typically these transformers are owned and maintained by the power delivery utility company. When you would need service at a particular current level the power company will deploy the proper transformers and then provide a power line connection from the transformer to the electrical usage meter which would be on or adjacent to the home or business.

Typical Transformers:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.featurepics.com/online/Powerline-Transformers-877799.aspx)*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](http://voltage-disturbance.com/power-engineering/power-engineering-impedance-of-transfromer/)*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.fortisbc.com/safety-outages/electricity-safety/padmounted-transformers)*</sup>

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

In most places in the US, residential power comes into the meter at 240V/120V - three conductors, 2 hot and 1 neutral. The hots are 240V apart (there are some situations where they may 208V or some other value, but 240V is most common) and the hots are each 120V from neutral.

Typically there will be a transformer either on a pole or in an underground vault or on a street corner which transforms power from some higher voltage to 240V. But you don't need to worry about that. Your utility provides 240V, and how it gets there is up to them. In some large buildings, that transformer may even be inside the building, but you, as the ordinary consumer, only get 240V/120V.

If you have to upgrade the **entire** electrical system of a house, the safest thing to do is often to have the utility pull the meter (or lock it out in some fashion). That will make your main electrical panel "dead" so that it can be replaced safely. Once you have a new main panel with a shutoff of some sort (either a main breaker or a separate shutoff switch) then any additional work can be done with the meter connected and power "live" to the house.

Comment: Just curious, so is the voltage of the power line on the street much higher than 240V? How high is it?

Comment: It could 240V for anywhere from your closest pole to several houses down the street. Then it will jump up to something higher - potentially multiple steps, possibly as high as 13,000V. A lot depends on the particular utility and how far you are from a power substation.

Comment: @Hans The next step depends on the population density and other factors (as how much high the poles can be in the area). Here in Europe, it is called "intermediate voltage grid" and can be anywhere from 1kV (legacy setups in a small vilages) up to 35kV for a brand new, power-hungry building complex. It is probably the same in US. Usually, you don't have to deal with the intermediate voltage, unless you are a big industrial power consumer that has its own power transformers and get the power directly at the higher voltage (it is cheaper).

Comment: In addition, you will notice (in the photos) that things come in threes. Most power companies run 3-phase supplies (plus an earth safety) down your street with 415 (or 208) volt AC. Your house supply is tapped off any two of the three phases, which reduces the phase voltage by a factor of sqrt(3).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant  To be a pedant, the house supply is tapped off of **one** of the three phases (using **two** of the three *wires*).  The grid is all delta, so the phases are the three line-line combinations (ie: A-B, B-C, C-A)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, 3-phase power doesn't always have an earth connection, and even when it does it's not for personal safety.

Comment: @J..., The grid isn't always delta. Sometimes it's WYE, but the higher voltage or longer distance transmission the more likely to be delta.

Comment: @Ben Ok fair, but where the grid is WYE it won't supply a neutral so it's effectively still a three wire system - you never get a line-neutral phase on the grid side of a consumer transformer, I don't believe.

Comment: @J..., I think you can get both as noted [here](https://www.powerandtest.com.cn/service-and-support/app-notes-faqs/~/-/media/ametekprogrammablepower/files/pdfs/ac-power-distribution.pdf). (Pages 4 and 5). Note that 480 is a commercial/industrial voltage, not residential.

Comment: @Ben Yes, but that's consumer side.  Of course you get a neutral where it's going to be used, but it's the same story as the 120/240 split for residential, the grid is delta (or wye without neutral) behind the consumer transformer, it only becomes WYE (with neutral) at the consumer side of the distribution transformer, not on the grid side.  There's never a need to have the extra wire for just distribution.

Comment: +1. Informative answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the potential/voltage of the power line on a city street?

Usually distribution 2300, 4160, 12.47k, or 13.8k, but can be higher. Transmission would be higher and can be run around city streets, but would generally go to a substation.

> Where does the potential/voltage of the line drop to the indoor value, e.g., 110 V in the US?

As shown by Michael, there are transformers that convert the higher voltage to lower voltage to your house. The voltage to a residence is 240V, but between two lines. The 120 (110) that you refer to is between one line and neutral.

> If I need to upgrade the whole electric circuitry of a house, do I need to worry about the high voltage and if so, where does the high voltage starts to drop down to the indoor value coming into the house?

The lower 240V lines will start at the transformer. This is either on the pole, or on a padmount transformer. In a residence, the voltage would only be 240V.

If you are modifying or updating in your residence, you'll either use 120V (single pole), or 240V (double pole). You would choose based on the need of the line. Generally, you'll always use a single unless it's a high load device such as an electric oven or air conditioner. Devices are built for a voltage and you'll just need to supply what they need. When in doubt, you can ask at a hardware store, or get  help from an electrician.

Comment: +1. Informative answer. Thank you.